# Migrate stored procedure on SQL Server to HPL/SQL (Hadoop ecosystem)

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, hive-hplsql

I have a project which required migrating all the stored procedure from SQL Server to Hadoop ecosystem.

So the main point makes me concerned that if HPL/SQL is terminated or not up-to-date as in http://www.hplsql.org/new. It shows latest updated features HPL/SQL 0.3.31-September 2011,2017

Has anyone been using this open source tool and this kind of migration is feasible basing on your experience? Very highly appreciated your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue of migrating a huge amount of stored procedures from traditional RDBMS to Hadoop.

Firstly, this project is still active. It is included in Apache Hive since version 2.0 and that's why it stopped releasing individually since September 2017. You could download the latest version of HPL/SQL from the [hive repo](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/hplsql).

You may have a look at the [git history](https://github.com/apache/hive/commits/master/hplsql) for new features and bug fixes.

Comment: Well thank you, this was good input for my project. However we stop implementing this way due to wasting too much human resources than rebuilding them on Hive.